# Explanation for the listed output of "fsck"

Tags: fsck

I just executed the `fsck` command to check my drive using below:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda2
```

And I got the following output:

```
/dev/sda2: 1735/32768000 files (22,9 % non-contiguous), 57400225/131072000
```

Is the file system ok? I mean, it should state clean if the filesystem is ok. Am I right?

Comment: Can you run `fsck` again, but with the `-vf` option and add the output to your question?  Make sure the drive is unmounted first.

Comment: okey, hold on..

Comment: What filesystem is this? Do `sudo fsck -V /dev/sda2` and post the complete output. Not all filesystem fsck programs print "clean". FAT doesn't, for example.